# Is there any way to drop the <li> when it is taken out of the conatiner div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

i have a requirement in which  i have a container div that contains 3 `<ul>` on which dragsort is attached stucture is comething like

```
<div id="container">

    <ul id="list1">
        <li><div>a</div></li>
        <li><div>a</div></li>
        <li><div>a</div></li>
        <li><div>a</div></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="list2">
        <li><div>b</div></li>
        <li><div>b</div></li>
        <li><div>b</div></li>
        <li><div>b</div></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="list3">
        <li><div>c</div></li>
        <li><div>c</div></li>
        <li><div>c</div></li>
        <li><div>c</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Requirement:**

these item are dragged & drop in between these lists . but item should not be taken out of the container div (visually not) is there any way to detach the mouse from the item when somone is trying to drag item out of the container div

like there is

```
containment: "#containment-wrapper" in jquery  .draggable(
```

reference:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: Can you clean up your code examples? Very tough to read...Oh, thanks, @jfriend00. :)

Comment: So you want additional functionality that says when dragging don't let the mouse exit the box?

Comment: @Brogrammer - I was just thinking that... Wondering if it's because he asks the questions in ways that are unanswerable or if he doesn't bother to pick an answer

Comment: I cleaned up your code sample, but you need to go back and accept those answers from previous questions that were helpful. Otherwise no one is going to want to spend time trying to answer your questions.

Comment: @Dan - While this question, if I understand it, it quite answerable... at least half of the questions he asked have no answers and many that do are not really answers they are suggestions because the questions does not really facilitate an answer...

Comment: @Umbrella - You need to word your questions better so you get better answers... also when you get a good answer, you should upvote it/mark it as an answer... Hopefully someone does answer this question because I', actually curious to see what it is....

Comment: @kralco626 Makes sense. Now I'm curious what the previous questions were :)

Comment: @Dan - quite a variety of questions on his question list... a lot of the technologies I have certainly never worked with... proly why he doesn't get a lot of answers... still he could follow up his own questions with his efforts to solve it, or post answers with his solutions...

Comment: Either he is solving the problems himself and not posting the solutions as he should... or he is not getting a lot of stuff he is supposed to do done... because he has a lot of unanswered questions...

Comment: Exactly i have lots of questions that are unanswered ..... while i m putting effort on them , but did not get any work around.

Comment: secondly i dont like to misguide other ., for the specific problem i did not find any appropriate answer, so how can i accept it .

Comment: thirdly i am very active for finding workarounds & options for my problems & stucking issues ... '

Comment: hey .... what .. no one is here to answer the question ..... So, why are u all expecting me to accept any answer ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want containment functionality in jquery dragsort plugin

If you're referring to [jQuery List DragSort](http://dragsort.codeplex.com/), it is coded to contain the dragged item within a container but only inside UL if you're not dragging between lists. So to specify a custom container you will need to modify the code. So find this in the code:

```
if (!opts.dragBetween) {
    var containerHeight = $(list.container).outerHeight() == 0 ? Math.max(1, Math.round(0.5 + list.getItems().size() * list.draggedItem.outerWidth() / $(list.container).outerWidth())) * list.draggedItem.outerHeight() : $(list.container).outerHeight();
    list.offsetLimit = $(list.container).offset();
    list.offsetLimit.right = list.offsetLimit.left + $(list.container).outerWidth() - list.draggedItem.outerWidth();
    list.offsetLimit.bottom = list.offsetLimit.top + containerHeight - list.draggedItem.outerHeight();
}
```

And replace with:

```
if (!opts.dragBetween || typeof opts.containment != "undefined") {
    var box = typeof opts.containment != "undefined" ? $(opts.containment) : $(list.container);
    var containerHeight = box.outerHeight() == 0 ? Math.max(1, Math.round(0.5 + list.getItems().size() * list.draggedItem.outerWidth() / box.outerWidth())) * list.draggedItem.outerHeight() : box.outerHeight();
    list.offsetLimit = box.offset();
    list.offsetLimit.right = list.offsetLimit.left + box.outerWidth() - list.draggedItem.outerWidth();
    list.offsetLimit.bottom = list.offsetLimit.top + containerHeight - list.draggedItem.outerHeight();
}
```

Next find this:

```
if (!opts.dragBetween) {
    top = Math.min(this.offsetLimit.bottom, Math.max(top, this.offsetLimit.top));
    left = Math.min(this.offsetLimit.right, Math.max(left, this.offsetLimit.left));
}
```

And replace with this:

```
if (this.offsetLimit != null) {
    top = Math.min(this.offsetLimit.bottom, Math.max(top, this.offsetLimit.top));
    left = Math.min(this.offsetLimit.right, Math.max(left, this.offsetLimit.left));
}
```

Now invoke dragsort like this:

```
$("#container ul").dragsort({ containment: "#container", dragBetween: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

HTML:

```
<div id="draggable_containment">
     <div id="draggable_content">Draggable content here</div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
var draggable_content = $('#draggable_content');
var draggable_containment = $('#draggable_containment');

draggable_content.draggable({ containment: draggable_containment });
```

CSS:

```
#draggable_containment { widht: 300px; height: 300px; }
```

TIP:

You could set width and height on the containment dynamically with javascript. If the child elements of the containment are absolute positioned it could result that the containment doesn't "stretch" as it should. This is why we need to set width and height.

Hope this helps you and sorry if my English is a little rusty.

Comment: hey i want containment functionality in jquery dragsort plugin

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation ok, sorry, must have been confused by the reference link to: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement